# SessionID: NotImplementedException on Unit Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq, mstest, mvccontrib

I am trying to create unit tests for my ASP.NET MVC project, but facing an issue that could not resolve since quite some time. I am always getting `NotImplementedException` on `Session.SessionID`:

> ```
> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
>     at MvcContrib.TestHelper.MockSession.get_SessionID()
> ```

Here is my `TestMethod`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CannAddCategory()
{
    TestControllerBuilder controllerBuilder = new TestControllerBuilder();

    this.Login();

    HomeController controller = new HomeController();
    controllerBuilder.InitializeController(controller);

    GetAllQuestionsFromInitialCategory(controller);
}
```

I tried to debug the method, in order to find out the issue, but the error is the same:

```
System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'
```

on

```
this.context = ContextSessionStore.GetInstance().GetQuestionnaireContext(Session.SessionID);
```

I looked further in SO and there were some suggestions on mocking the Session manually. This did not work as well for me. The error remains.

Manual mocking of session:

```
var mock = new MockRepository();
var mockSession = mock.Stub<HttpSessionStateBase>();

controller.HttpContext.BackToRecord();
controller.HttpContext.Stub(c => c.Session).Return(mockSession);
controller.HttpContext.Replay()
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Controller method that uses `SessionID`:

```
protected QuestionnaireContext Database
{
    get
    {
        if (Session == null)
        {
            this.context = new QuestionnaireContext();
            return this.context;
        }

        this.context = ContextSessionStore.GetInstance().GetQuestionnaireContext(Session.SessionID);
        return this.context;
    }

    private set
    {
        this.context = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the controller code

Comment: @3dd added the method that uses SessionID

Comment: that lib cant be done. Or you are using it wrong. have a look at line 174... https://github.com/atomicobject/mvccontrib/blob/master/src/MvcContrib.TestHelper/MvcContrib.TestHelper/MockSession.cs